# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mdptoolbox'

Tags: python, mdptoolbox

I receive an error when importing the `mdptoolbox` module.

```
import mdptoolbox, mdptoolbox.example
```

**Error logs:**

---

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import mdptoolbox, mdptoolbox.example
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mdptoolbox'

**How can I resolve the error?**

Comment: just do this pip install pymdptoolbox it will work

Answer (score 3):

Those suggestions are definitely correct if OP is trying to import the `pymdptoolbox` package.

However I got the same error message when trying to import the `mpdtoolbox-hiive` version (https://pypi.org/project/mdptoolbox-hiive/#description). Just wanted to share the imports that worked for me:

```
import hiive.mdptoolbox, hiive.mdptoolbox.example
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you haven't installed the mdptoolbox package :

Go through this for the complete installation and usage of the module :
https://github.com/sawcordwell/pymdptoolbox

Comment: type in terminal pip install pymdptoolbox and then pip install "pymdptoolbox[LP]" which installs me-toolbox package